# Steps to setup and work with Specflow, Selenium, Nunit, .NET Core using Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, visual-studio-2017, nunit, specflow

Installed Specflow  via Nuget Package Manager in VS2017 however in visual studio Specflow items nothing was showing. Uninstalled Visual Studio and Reinstalled VS 2017 Enterprise edition.

Please help Sequential Steps for clean setup of installation and working with Specflow, Selenium, C#, Nunit, .NET Core in Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019 and get started with a BDD example.

Comment: You'll need to read the documentation from the official [SpecFlow web site](https://specflow.org), and look up **behavior driven development**. One of my favorites sites for BDD is [Automation Panda](https://automationpanda.com/bdd/). As is, your question is pretty broad, and asking for references or documentation is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow-Examples/tree/master/MSBuild/OldCSProj_SpecFlow30) is a project with latest Specflow that will help you get started. It also uses a very simple example of BDD feature files as required by you.  I used this  with  VS2019 .